# XtraGrid column checked list filter problem

Tags: c#, .net, xtragrid

I am using XtraGrid in my application. I have shown checked list box with unique values for the column filter. Now, I want to enumerate which Items were checked once the dialog disappears after clicking OK button. How to do this?

Thanks,
Omky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't know the exact implementation of your checked listbox in the filter popup, you can handle the `ColumnFilterChanged` event on the GridView. Then, I suggest that you analyse the FilterCriteria of your column and see which value are being used for filtering.

```
private void gridView1_ColumnFilterChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var filteredValues = new List<string>();

    var criteria = gridColumn1.FilterInfo.FilterCriteria;

    if (criteria is GroupOperator)
    {
        var group = (GroupOperator)criteria;
        foreach (var operand in group.Operands.OfType<BinaryOperator>())
        {
            var value = (OperandValue)operand.RightOperand;
            filteredValues.Add(value.Value.ToString());
        }
    }
    else if(criteria is BinaryOperator)
    {
        var value = (OperandValue)((BinaryOperator)criteria).RightOperand;
        filteredValues.Add(value.Value.ToString());

    }

    // Do something with the filtered values
}
```

Comment: Its not the separate column. It the popup dialog that come up when you set following property on column.// Enable the checked filter dropdown list for the Category Name column.
colCategoryName.OptionsFilter.FilterPopupMode = 
    DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.FilterPopupMode.CheckedList;         How to know which items are checked or unchecked in this dialog box????