# XTraGrid Filter Expression Parsing

Tags: c#, .net, xtragrid

I want to parse the XTraGrid filter string expression to get the Column(S) name and their values(on which they are filtered) in the expression. Is there any way to do it?

Thanks
Omkay

Comment: is this the same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011853/xtragrid-column-checked-list-filter-problem ??

Comment: Yes. I want to achieve the similar thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use the following events:

[CustomFilterDialog](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CustomFilterDialogtopic)

[CustomFilterDisplayText](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CustomFilterDisplayTexttopic)